# Fuzzy index on dataset

Tags: sql, search, lucene, fuzzy-search

I'm facing a problem where I need to provide a search functionality where
a user can supply "as much information as he/she knows". This dataset should then be
matched against different lookup tables to determine if I reliably can associate it
against one of our local id's. e.g If we have a record for this search query.
Most of the fields are fuzzy.

**Example:**
One field could be name (where the user only have the first name) and another street
where the user only have the street number.

The dataset is of medium size (~10M entries).

What is the best approche for this problem? SQL + soundex? lucene?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is already a bit old. I'm searching for something similar. What are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

You can score documents in Lucene and compare similarity. Inverted index tool like Lucene should be faster and much more scalable than traditional key-value lookups in SQL.